# Ember Application performance

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

This may be extremely noobish, but I couldnt hold this doubt, In ember we write all our HTML using handlebar templates which is javascript, so if I have n **different** pages then I'd have say n handlebar templates, Also each template is an Object (I used build tools so I have this hash `Ember.TEMPLATES` which stores all my templates)

More Templates => More Properties in `Ember.TEMPLATES` Hash => My App.js would be larger in size, also much memory is used to hold that Hash

First doubt is as we are shipping the entire javascript all at once, it will increase the load time of the application, the plus point is the web-application interaction is much faster once it is loaded

Also as much memory is used to hold the Hash, web application will use much resources.

Firstly, is there anything wrong with my assumptions ? if not then is it the price we pay for having much interactive web applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it all depends on the way that you go about loading your other resources. Yes, the JavaScript will take longer to load than the JavaScript of a web application that is not built in the client.

But remember, this load time is still significantly less than the "total" load time of "normal" apps, where each page that a user visits creates another HTTP request and thus has to reload its JavaScript over and over again.

Also, because Ember is asynchronous, you can design your app in a way that makes it load less other external resources initially (images, data etc) and have those be pulled in using the DS.Store mechanism, so your initial load time can be only the JS/HTML/CSS and everything else can come later (no more waiting for that expensive database query on your server).

So yes, Ember does equal more initial JavaScript load time, but it provides you with tools to lower the total load time of your app.

As for browser resources, Ember is pretty efficient, but using more browser memory is just the price we pay for having the computations happening on the client's machine rather than on our own servers. The idea is that *most* modern browsers and machines are good enough to handle this extra resource requirement so the trade-off becomes worth it.

Edit:

It may be that your app is just too big for browsers to handle, no matter what you do (although your app has to be pretty massive for that to be the case). In that case, a way to tackle it is to break it into multiple Ember apps along lines that will minimize your users switching back and forth between Ember apps. Maybe a "public" app that handles login, marketing, viewing content etc and a "private" app that handles back-end account pages.

Comment: I would particularly love to know how do we go loading the images, data etc later as you have mentioned, I deployed a website built using ember(Ofcourse a single minified javascript file & a single minified css file, did server side concatenation), but still it takes much time to load the page, on mobile devices or on low bandwidth connection, it stops loading after some span of the time and displays a blank page !

Comment: Each piece is as full post in and of itself. And it also really depends a lot on what your app does. But as an example, if one of the heavy parts of your app is user avatars. Instead of loading every user and their avatars on initial page load, you can have a model User with an attribute avatar that only gets loaded via the router (using Ember Data) when you visit the /users page. 

The same principle can be applied to many different parts of the app to reduce load requirements.

Also putting in an edit above that may help with apps that are just too big.

Comment: Caching your resources or consuming them (images/css/js) from a CDN would be really helpful for most of these cases. Use CDN whenever possible.